# Comparing data from JSON

Tags: android, json, service

I am using a service to get a count value from JSON array which is for example `count=3`.
Service Runs after every 20 second and returns a new count value.
Now For example we have new count value `count=3`.
I want to compare **new count** value with the previous **count** value.
For Example:
1st Time Service Runs:

```
count=3
```

2nd Time Service Runs:

```
count=5
```

Now How to compare count=5 to count = 3.

3rd Time Service Runs:

```
count=6
```

Now compare `count=6` to `count =5`
And so on...
Any Help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Below is MyService.class

```
public class GettingUpdate extends Service {
private int first=0;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Quack Toast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new ServAsynch().execute();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private class ServAsynch extends AsyncTask {


    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        String urlQuack="Someurl";

        try {
            System.out.println("test");
            URL url = new URL(Someurl);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

                result.append(line);

            }
            System.out.println("testRes");
            System.out.println("RESULT:" + result);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(result));
            JSONObject jo = jsonObject.optJSONObject("metadata");
            String count = jo.optString("count");
            System.out.println("Count: "+count);
            first =Integer.parseInt(count);
            }  catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return  null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);


    }
}enter code here
```

Comment: what do you want to do, when you compare them ?

Comment: Then I will show a local notification

Comment: Do you want to compare your previous value with new value?
If yes you can use Shared Preference to store previous value.

Comment: @Shivang Thnx its also a good suggestion i will Keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare new count value with the previous count value, just keep it, outside of your method.

make it static to retain it.

in your class, declare:

```
static int last=-1;
```

int your method:

declare first (not declared)

```
int first =Integer.parseInt(count);
```

and then compare

```
            if (first==last)
                {
                // so domething 
                }
            else
                {
                // do another thing
                }
```

finaly, keep first

```
            last=first;
```

If you want to keep all the values, use a Vector for example:

```
static vector<Integer> counts=new vector<Integer>;
```

etc.

it helps ?

Comment: Thnx it quite work for me can u explain your logic a bit.. It will be great Help..

Comment: what to explain: how to keep the value, or the Vector ?

Comment: How to keep the value

Comment: text modified at top.